# Spring Boot Validations with annotations

Tags: spring, validation, annotations

I am trying to validate the RequestBody using @Valid. Here is an article I read about this: https://dimitr.im/validating-the-input-of-your-rest-api-with-spring.      Here is my code:

```
 @PutMapping("/update")
    public ResponseEntity<?> update(@RequestBody @Valid ProfileDTO medicationDTO) {
        try {
            profileService.update(medicationDTO);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity
                    .badRequest()
                    .body(new MessageResponseDTO("Error: User not found!"));
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponseDTO("User updated successfully!"));
    }
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ProfileDTO {

    private Integer userId;
    private String username;
    private String email;

    @NotBlank(message = "First name cannot be empty.")
    @Min(1)
    private String firstName;

    @NotBlank(message = "Last name cannot be empty.")
    @Min(1)
    private String lastName;

    @NotBlank(message = "Registration plate cannot be empty.")
    @Min(1)
    private String registrationPlate;
}
```

However, when I try sending this from Postman status 200 is returned:

```
{
    "userId": "2",
    "firstName": "",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "registrationPlate": "AB20CDE"
}
```

Why isn't the validation working?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `BindingResult` right after the medicationDTO, like:

```java
    public ResponseEntity<?> update(@RequestBody @Valid ProfileDTO medicationDTO, BindingResult bindingResult)
```

And you need to check if `bindingResult.hasErrors()` is true and then throw the exception you want.

Comment: That might not be needed (it's not in the sample article at least).  How is this one different?

Comment: I have just found this somewhere and tried it. Still nothing.

Comment: That's strange it's exactly how I use it and it works like a charm, beware that `BindingResult` **must** be the next parameter after the object you want to validate

Comment: This is what I tried:
public ResponseEntity<?> update(@RequestBody @Valid ProfileDTO medicationDTO, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return ResponseEntity
                    .badRequest()
                    .body(new MessageResponseDTO("Empty fields"));
        }

Comment: Have you try stopping the debugger at the `if (bindingResult.hasErrors())` line and verify the DTO you are receiving? Is your class annotated with @RestController? Have you try other validations alone, like `@NotNull` and sending a null value? The validator should be automagically provided by Spring for `@Controller` and `@RestController`

Comment: @sebasira The class is annotated with `@RestController`. And I have just tried `@NotNull` and still nothing. When pausing with the debugger, the BindingResult has the ProfileDTO as a target but errors' list is empty.