# Annotation @Valid in RestController always returning status code 200

Tags: spring-boot, validation, annotations, spring-restcontroller

I followed multiple posts online like
https://www.javatpoint.com/restful-web-services-validations
https://reflectoring.io/bean-validation-with-spring-boot/
and many more.

Everywhere it is written that just by adding @Valid in-front of @RequestBody will check validation of the input. But for me it always returns status code as 200 although using JUnit test cases I am able to validate all the restrictions.

Also I followed posts like [Spring Boot Validations with annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62220315/spring-boot-validations-with-annotations)
And added BindingResult as 2nd parameter, still the behaviour is same and bindingResult object shows 0 errors.

Details are below:

DTO Class:

```
package practice.corejava.validators.dto;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Positive;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserData {

    @NotBlank(message = "Name should not be blank")
    private String name;

    @NotNull(message = "Age should not be null")
    @Positive(message = "Age should be positive")
    private Integer age;

}
```

Controller Class: (Always returning 201 via Postman)

```
package practice.corejava.validators.controller;

import practice.corejava.validators.dto.UserData;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;

import jakarta.validation.Valid;

import java.net.URI;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/validations")
public class ValidationsController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/user-data", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<UserData> createUserData(@Valid @RequestBody UserData userData) {
        URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{name}").buildAndExpand(userData.getName()).toUri();
        return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
    }

}
```

JUnit Test Class: (Test cases are succeeding)

```
package practice.corejava.validators.dto;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import jakarta.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import jakarta.validation.Validation;
import jakarta.validation.Validator;
import jakarta.validation.ValidatorFactory;
import java.util.Set;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class UserDataTest {

    private static Validator validator;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void setUp() {
        try (ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory()) {
            validator = factory.getValidator();
        }
    }

    @Test
    void all_validation_success() {
        UserData userData = new UserData("SomeName", 30);
        Set<ConstraintViolation<UserData>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(userData);
        assertEquals(0, constraintViolations.size());
    }

    @Test
    void name_blank() {
        UserData userData = new UserData("", 30);
        Set<ConstraintViolation<UserData>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(userData);
        assertEquals(1, constraintViolations.size());
        assertEquals("Name should not be blank", constraintViolations.iterator().next().getMessage());
    }

}
```

Postman request body: Expected 400 but 201 coming as status code

```
{
    "name" : null,
    "age" : 30
}
```

See "Dependencies and Versions" details below:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Which dependencies ar eyou using, which spring boot version, what does your test look like. Is this your actual code or some dumbed down version. Please use code **with imports** that way we know what you are actually using.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Let me update all other details too.

Comment: @M.Deinum As of now, I am trying it as a practice project, once it works good then I will use similar code in my project. So this is the actual code for now. I have updated other relevant details too. Thanks again for your response.

Comment: Remove `validation-api`, `hibernate-validator` and `javax.el` add `spring-boot-starter-validation`. Fix compilation errors by renamed `javax.validation` to `jakarta.validation`. You are using JavaEE versions of the Validation API which aren't suported by Spring boot 3.x.

Comment: Let me try and will update you.

Comment: Tried adding jakarta.validation-api (3.0.2 version) and removed others. Controller behaviour through Postman is still the same(i.e., always 200 status code) but now tests cases are failing with below error:

jakarta.validation.NoProviderFoundException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Jakarta Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.
 at jakarta.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:291)
 at jakarta.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:103)

Comment: Added hibernate-validator(6.0.21.Final) and javax.el(3.0.0) as before, still the same. Will try once with jakarta.el too

Comment: Sigh... Don't add individual dependencies add `spring-boot-starter-validation` as I stated in the comment.

Comment: same with jakarta.el(4.0.2) too

Comment: ah sorry, will add that.

Comment: Last... Add `spring-boot-starter-validation` as I mentioned in the comments (twice) instead of individual dependencies!

Comment: Fixed the pom. Tests cases passing too but the response is still the same through Postman. (i.e, always returning success)

Let me update the latest code and dependencies in the post too

Comment: @M.Deinum looks like there was a delay in Maven update. I tried restarting my IDE and did clean install, maven update again. And now it is working like a charm. Thanks a lot for your response and detailed guidance.

Comment: @M.Deinum if it is fine with you, please paste the same comment in Answer section too so that I will accept it and mark this as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by M. Deinum in comments, the dependencies that I was using was incompatible with Spring boot 3.x. and hence the response was not coming as expected. After updating with the suggested changes, now it is perfectly working. Thanks a lot for your suggestions and time @M. Deinum

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, after adding dependency `spring-boot-starter-validation` the problem was solved.

Comment: thanks for your comment @Vitalii . It got resolved for me too in the same way.